# Correct C# code to parse this string into a date

Tags: c#

I have the following code that refuses to be parsed into a date:

```
20130718-18:15:36.038
```

Does anyone know what the correct C# code is to parse it using System.Datetime.Parse() is?

Thanks.

Comment: Because your code is wrong. Post it next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20130718-18:15:36.038", "yyyyMMdd\\-HH\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff", null);
```

All the format strings are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

As a side note, make sure you use the backslashes before the special characters to tell the code that you want to use that specific character exactly as-is instead of a system value (and the double-backslash here is C#'s escaping a single backslash). Alternatively you could do `@"yyyyMMdd\-HH\:mm\:ss\.fff"`.

Comment: I would advise just using `-` and `:`, but specifying the invariant culture. Not that it matters for `-` anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've personally never been a fan of `InvariantCulture` - the colon is still a special "time separator", even though InvariantCulture may simply translate the colon to itself. It's probably just my paranoia, but if I'm parsing a string where I know exactly what characters I've got, I'd rather give it the exact character instead of trusting that .NET's implementation of InvariantCulture is future-proof, and that the hyphen will never mean something special somewhere down the road. I may have trust issues :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string theDate = "20130718-18:15:36.038";

DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(theDate, "yyyyMMdd\\-HH\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```